# How to make a column with data type Bit and lenght 4 in sqlalchemy for mariadb or mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have not found a way to do this as the BIT data type in sqlalchemy inherits from Boolean datatype.

```
    flags = Column(BIT(4), nullable=False)  # BIT column with length 4

sql: `flags` BIT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
```

AttributeError: 'BIT' object has no attribute 'length'

Comment: [appears to be there](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/94d20a225b4806f89a399da4704724284356598c/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/types.py#L368), and [obviously valid](https://dbfiddle.uk/aEi6Jda0). Which DBAPI and sqlachemy version?

Comment: `BIT` is only partially supported by MySQL/MariaDB.  `TINYINT UNSIGNED` will hold up to 8 bits.  There is no datatype smaller than one byte.

Comment: "the BIT data type in sqlalchemy inherits from Boolean" - That is true for mssql (MS SQL Server) but not for mysql/mariadb. It sounds like you are using the wrong SQLAlchemy dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIT is not a standard data type (neither in SQL Standard nor in SQLAlchemy) but it is supported by e.g. PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MariaDB and MySQL.

As @danblack already mentioned in his comment, BIT type is defined in types.py (but also in base.py as MSBit).
That means you have to use types of your dialect, in this case mysql (mariadb is also stored under dialects/mysql).

e.g.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.types import BIT

....

table_def= Table('my_table', meta,
                 Column('flags', BIT(4), nullable=False))
```

Comment: this works, i was doing 
```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import BIT
```